# how to format USB Flash Disk using Ubuntu terminal

Tags: format

I'm a total newbie in Linux specially Ubuntu, I'm just asking on how to format a USB using Ubuntu terminal. Hope you can help me thanks!

Comment: It is not that easy for a niewbie. Why do not use GUI tools?

Comment: If you make a mistake, you can format your HDD. There will be no warning.

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate (at least not the one marked). That one asks for a GUI, and this one for a command line solution...

Comment: @Calimo The other question has been broadened to include command-line solution, just the wording was never removed.

Answer (score 34):

- First, you have to find out which device (`/dev/sd??`) your USB stick is. Therefore look at the output of

  ```
  sudo fdisk -l
  ```
- After that unmount the device/partition (if necessary) by running

  ```
  sudo umount /dev/sd??
  ```

  Make sure you replaced `??` with the correct device/partition name from the previous output.
- To format The partition as FAT32 use

  ```
  sudo mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/sd??
  ```

  Again replace `??` with your respective letters.

**Be careful that if you enter the wrong device name, you might also accidentally format your hard disk!**

**You can also do**

```
    sudo -s
```

**and you don't have to put "sudo" in front of everything!**

Comment: Hi, after doing this I get a:
`Error while copying to XXXXX
The destination is read-only.`
any clue?

Comment: sudo chmod 777 /dev/sd??

Comment: Have a SCRIPT for the whole shebang would be nice (with some sanity checks, that it's a a) USB b) removable device c) no larger than 32 GB d) unrelated to the usual pack like `/`, `/boot`, etc. as an extra precaution)

Comment: If you want to name the volume while formatting, add `-n YOUR-NAME` to the `mkdosfs` command.

Comment: I know it's been 4 years but @vabada you probably messed with the usb too much and it's broken