# Impossible to format usb drive Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb-drive

I try to format an old usb drive that I didn't use for a long time, but I am not able to do it , either using `disk` or using `gparted`.
[image]

This is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57b4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB Camera
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 10c4:8105 Silicon Labs USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

this is the output of `fsck`:

```
sudo fsck -n /dev/sdb
fsck da util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Valore magic non corretto nel super-blocco
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Valore magic non corretto nel super-blocco durante il tentativo di apertura di /dev/sdb

The super-blocco could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
file system.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
file system (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the super-blocco
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate super-blocco:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdb
```

This is the output of `fdisk`:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 7,63 GiB, 8178892800 bytes, 15974400 sectors
Disk model: Flash Disk      
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x17823189
```

this is the last part of the output of `dmesg`:

```
[14705.497588] perf: interrupt took too long (2527 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79000
[15092.403965] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[15092.558763] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387, bcdDevice= 1.04
[15092.558766] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[15092.558768] usb 1-3: Product: Mass Storage
[15092.558769] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Generic
[15092.558771] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: BBD4E3A0
[15092.581576] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[15092.581691] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[15092.581809] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[15092.584060] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[15093.601856] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[15093.602374] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[15093.603112] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 15974400 512-byte logical blocks: (8.18 GB/7.62 GiB)
[15093.603804] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[15093.603809] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[15093.604526] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[15093.653603] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[15210.713521] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[15210.713525] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[15210.713539] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 <<vendor>>ASC=0xff <<vendor>>ASCQ=0xff 
[15210.713542] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 f0 00
[15210.713545] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 8192 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[15210.713549] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1024, lost async page write
[15210.713556] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1025, lost async page write
[15210.713558] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1026, lost async page write
[15210.713560] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1027, lost async page write
[15210.713561] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1028, lost async page write
[15210.713563] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1029, lost async page write
[15210.713565] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1030, lost async page write
[15210.713567] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1031, lost async page write
[15210.713568] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1032, lost async page write
[15210.713570] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1033, lost async page write
[15210.714074] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[15210.714076] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[15210.714077] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[15210.714079] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 20 f0 00 00 f0 00
[15210.714080] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 8432 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[15210.714507] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[15210.714508] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[15210.714509] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[15210.714510] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 21 e0 00 00 f0 00
[15210.714511] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 8672 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[15210.714923] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[15210.714925] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[15210.714927] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[15210.714929] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 22 d0 00 00 f0 00
[15210.714931] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 8912 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[15210.715391] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[15210.715394] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[15210.715397] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[15210.715400] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 23 c0 00 00 f0 00
[15210.715403] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 9152 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[15210.715838] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[15210.715840] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[15210.715842] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[15210.715844] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 24 b0 00 00 f0 00
[15210.715846] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 9392 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[15210.716253] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[15210.716254] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[15210.716256] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[15210.716257] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 25 a0 00 00 f0 00
[15210.716258] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 9632 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[15210.716664] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[15210.716665] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[15210.716666] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[15210.716667] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 26 90 00 00 f0 00
[15210.716668] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 9872 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[15210.718295] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[15210.718296] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[15210.718298] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[15210.718299] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 27 80 00 00 80 00
[15210.718301] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 10112 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 16 prio class 0
[15316.593424] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is on
[15316.593426] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 80 00
[16009.586286] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[16015.783512] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[16015.942326] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387, bcdDevice= 1.04
[16015.942329] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[16015.942331] usb 1-3: Product: Mass Storage
[16015.942332] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Generic
[16015.942333] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: BBD4E3A0
[16015.943315] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[16015.943502] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[16016.957220] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[16016.957573] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[16016.958186] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 15974400 512-byte logical blocks: (8.18 GB/7.62 GiB)
[16016.958829] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[16016.958835] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[16016.959528] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[16017.000891] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[16407.792871]  sdb:
[16408.222075]  sdb:
[16408.450247]  sdb:
[16428.505641]  sdb: sdb1
[16428.761331]  sdb: sdb1
[16429.734196] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[16429.734199] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[16429.734202] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[16429.734204] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 f3 bc 00 00 00 f0 00
[16429.734206] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 15973376 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[16429.734210] buffer_io_error: 246 callbacks suppressed
[16429.734211] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1996672, lost async page write
[16429.734216] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1996673, lost async page write
[16429.734218] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1996674, lost async page write
[16429.734219] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1996675, lost async page write
[16429.734221] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1996676, lost async page write
[16429.734222] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1996677, lost async page write
[16429.734224] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1996678, lost async page write
[16429.734225] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1996679, lost async page write
[16429.734226] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1996680, lost async page write
[16429.734229] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1996681, lost async page write
[16429.735832] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[16429.735834] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[16429.735836] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[16429.735837] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 f3 bc f0 00 00 f0 00
[16429.735839] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 15973616 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[16429.736253] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[16429.736254] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[16429.736256] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[16429.736257] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 f3 bd e0 00 00 f0 00
[16429.736259] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 15973856 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[16429.736655] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[16429.736657] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[16429.736658] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[16429.736660] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 f3 be d0 00 00 f0 00
[16429.736662] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 15974096 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 30 prio class 0
[16429.737078] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[16429.737079] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[16429.737081] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[16429.737082] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 f3 bf c0 00 00 38 00
[16429.737084] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 15974336 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[16433.472029] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[16433.472032] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[16433.472034] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write protected
[16433.472036] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[16433.472038] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[16434.439443] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is on
[16434.439446] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 80 00
[16434.440756]  sdb: sdb1
[16787.242098] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 5
[16806.247433] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[16806.404622] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0dd8, idProduct=3200, bcdDevice=11.00
[16806.404630] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[16806.404634] usb 1-3: Product: OnlyDisk
[16806.404637] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Netac
[16806.404641] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: CCYYMM2ON9SW3YWR
[16806.405936] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[16806.406196] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[16807.496087] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Netac    OnlyDisk         1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[16807.496429] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[16807.496603] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 121610240 512-byte logical blocks: (62.3 GB/58.0 GiB)
[16807.496714] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[16807.496717] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[16807.496835] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[16807.525762]  sdb: sdb1
[16807.526755] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[16839.687376] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[16845.047233] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[16860.667106] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[16860.903158] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[16861.035115] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[16861.271105] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[16861.507115] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[16861.507203] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[16861.715209] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[16861.923106] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[16862.055090] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[16862.055190] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[16862.263197] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[16862.475072] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[16862.475110] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 6
[16862.475119] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=54s
[16862.475122] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 07 3f 9f 80 00 00 08 00
[16862.475124] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 121610112 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[16862.483140] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 121610112 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[16862.483144] buffer_io_error: 119 callbacks suppressed
[16862.483145] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 15201264, async page read
[16862.683130] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[16862.811134] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[16863.047122] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[16863.287102] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[16863.419110] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[16863.655131] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[16863.763144] usb usb1-port3: attempt power cycle
[16864.415090] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[16864.415177] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[16864.623179] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[16864.831089] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[16864.963087] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[16864.963185] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[16865.171172] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[16865.383058] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 10, error -71
[16865.383134] usb usb1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
[17683.421334] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[17683.442384] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0dd8, idProduct=3200, bcdDevice=11.00
[17683.442390] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[17683.442393] usb 2-1: Product: OnlyDisk
[17683.442395] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Netac
[17683.442398] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: CCYYMM2ON9SW3YWR
[17683.505665] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[17683.506321] scsi host5: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[17684.584901] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Netac    OnlyDisk         1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[17684.585155] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[17684.585355] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 121610240 512-byte logical blocks: (62.3 GB/58.0 GiB)
[17684.585468] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[17684.585469] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[17684.585584] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[17684.599007]  sdb: sdb1
[17684.599823] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[17721.201094] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[17726.321089] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[17731.696999] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[17737.072916] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[17737.280920] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[17737.488237] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17737.696293] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17737.900936] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 2, error -71
[17738.108295] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17738.316294] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17738.520917] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 2, error -71
[17738.728277] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17738.936253] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17739.140912] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 2, error -71
[17739.156947] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[17739.156958] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=54s
[17739.156961] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 07 3f 9f 80 00 00 08 00
[17739.156964] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 121610112 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[17739.172966] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 121610112 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[17739.172971] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 15201264, async page read
[17739.436276] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17739.644297] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17739.848925] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[17740.060236] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17740.272291] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17740.476909] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[17740.484948] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
[17741.416280] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17741.628285] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17741.832900] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[17742.040252] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17742.248284] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[17742.452919] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[17742.460936] usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[18036.835564] perf: interrupt took too long (3162 > 3158), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63250
[18110.182683] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[18110.331776] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0dd8, idProduct=3200, bcdDevice=11.00
[18110.331779] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[18110.331782] usb 1-3: Product: OnlyDisk
[18110.331784] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Netac
[18110.331785] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: CCYYMM2ON9SW3YWR
[18110.332899] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[18110.333149] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[18111.423508] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Netac    OnlyDisk         1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[18111.423801] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[18111.424008] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 121610240 512-byte logical blocks: (62.3 GB/58.0 GiB)
[18111.424159] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[18111.424160] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[18111.424280] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[18111.453234]  sdb: sdb1
[18111.454354] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[18142.210696] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[18147.566577] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[18163.186390] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[18163.426384] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[18163.558401] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[18163.794382] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[18164.030395] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[18164.030533] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[18164.238513] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[18164.446383] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[18164.574325] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[18164.574415] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[18164.782462] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[18164.990358] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[18164.990401] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 11
[18164.990411] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=53s
[18164.990414] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 07 3f 9f 80 00 00 08 00
[18164.990416] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 121610112 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[18165.006421] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 121610112 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[18165.006427] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 15201264, async page read
[18165.162317] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[18165.290485] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[18165.526368] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[18165.762359] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[18165.890401] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[18166.126369] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[18166.238361] usb usb1-port3: attempt power cycle
[18166.898348] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[18166.898466] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[18167.106490] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[18167.314321] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 14, error -71
[18167.442361] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[18167.442481] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[18167.650474] usb 1-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[18167.862342] usb 1-3: device not accepting address 15, error -71
[18167.862407] usb usb1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
[18830.570517] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[18830.733336] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387, bcdDevice= 1.04
[18830.733340] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[18830.733342] usb 1-3: Product: Mass Storage
[18830.733344] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Generic
[18830.733345] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: BBD4E3A0
[18830.734584] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[18830.734791] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[18831.756341] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[18831.756931] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[18831.757777] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 15974400 512-byte logical blocks: (8.18 GB/7.62 GiB)
[18831.758510] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[18831.758520] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[18831.759232] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[18831.800906]  sdb: sdb1
[18831.803519] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I also try with a different OS , Win10, and it is also unable to format the usb telling me that the filesystem of the usb drive is read-only.

Is there any chance to format and make usable again the usb?
Thanks a lot

Andrea

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu problem, as you have demonstrated by trying it in Windows 10, and failing. Throw the USB in the trash. It is broken.

Comment: Yes, I know that is not a Ubuntu problem. But I would like to know if there is some possibility in Ubuntu to recover my usb drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question [USB Read-Only Filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774695/usb-read-only-filesystem)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB Read-Only Filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774695/usb-read-only-filesystem)

Comment: No, because in my case I do not have the partition table for `/dev/sdb` . If I try to create it with gparted I got an error that says that the drive is open in read-only mode...
In the question above, they have a partition `/dev/sdb1` for the device...

Comment: Actually, read this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/ (Scroll down for the answer with the most votes. Try those things to recover your drive. If those don't work, then follow the advice from @user68186)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @KGIII, I tried with `mkusb` but I got this error:

""The target device is unmounted and you can unplug it.
The system might not see the current partition table of the
target device unless you re-plug it.""

so I suppose that problem is still that I am not able to mount the device and create a partition table for it.
Is my usb key definitely dead ?

Comment: Yeah, it's likely dead. It happens.