# Can't do anything with USB stick Read-only file system

Tags: gparted, usb-drive, read-only

When I plug my USB stick in, I can't open it. Every time I try to do something with it I'm getting a `Read-only file system` error message. Do you have any idea how to mount and fix it?

GParted:

[image: gparted]

Comment: Does this happen with all USB sticks or only one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB Read-Only Filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774695/usb-read-only-filesystem)

Comment: Only with that one